# Switching to Google Workspace. Have lots of alias emails that were created as regular users. How does one change them to be aliases?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace

Title says it all. I probably have 20 "users", but I have to switch them to being aliases since I'll be billed for each of these users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to [delete the users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314) to "release" the email addresses, otherwise if you try to create the aliases with the exact same email addresses the Admin console will show an error saying that the email addresses are already in use.

Once you delete the users you can start creating the aliases. Be aware that there may be some propagation time (up to 24h) for the Admin console to "understand" that the email addresses have been released.

To create the aliases you must go to the list of users, then click the user you want to add the alias to and go to the "User information" section. Once there click "Alternate email addresses (email alias)" and you will be able to add the alias there. Be aware that aliases can only be added to a specific user. In case you want to have more users linked to that alias I would recommend creating a group and adding all the users to that group instead.

In case you don't like the group option, you could also leave the alias linked to one user and just create a [forwarding rule](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084) so that all the users you need receive a copy of the messages.

References:

- [How to delete users](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33314)
- [How to create user aliases](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33327)
- [How to create groups](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9400082)
- [How to create a forwarding rule](https://support.google.com/a/answer/6297084)
- [How propagation affects Google Workspace](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7514107)

Answer (score 0):

Following up on this. Were you able to migrate successfully? I am in a similar situation as OP. My concern is whether emails will get migrated correctly to these group email addresses. In our old email system we had a user called “support@domain.com” and now we essentially want that to be a group, whereby all the managers of it can send emails as if they were “support@domain.com”

Comment: I did migrate. I think I just exported the emails for archival purposes as I didn't need them in Google.